# Cordova Phonegap building backend into standalone app?

Tags: cordova

I'm converting a web application to work on Cordova. Is there a way to bundle backend code with it so that I can do REST type calls from the web pages to a locally hosted backend?

I'm required to make a standalone version of the entire site with front end and backend functionality bundled within the app. Is this at all possible with cordova?  I don't mind rewriting the backend in another language, but I still need the front end to remain relatively untouched, so that requires that I be able to do some sort of XHR request to the locally hosted backend code.

Basically I guess, can cordova act as a web server to itself?

Comment: Would your "Backend" needs to do some complex things or does it just provides data?

Comment: @Kris Provide data and maybe use a web socket or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the same web interface to your cordova app given you have made it responsive using either in app browser 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

or using `window.open("some_url")`

Alternatively you can build an API for both the web and mobile app and the web app to communicate with the backend.

Hope this helps. :)